# Function/filter or plugin to change post status based on custom field value

Tags: posts, post-status

I am looking for a way to change the post status of some posts based on custom field value, from published to pending for example. How might this be possible?

My solution:

```
$post_ids = array( 1235, 1234, 1228, 1221, 1211, 1212, 1208, 1200 );

foreach($post_ids as $post_id) {
    $post = array( 'ID' => $post_id, 'post_status' => 'pending' );
    wp_update_post($post);
}
```

Comment: How/when do you want the action to be triggered?

Comment: It's for posts that are already in the database only, so it will be a one-time thing to set to pending posts that have a custom field with a certain value. With new posts going forward I won't have this value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paste this onto any page and load the page (or make it a function in functions.php and call that function somewhere)

```
$args = array(
    'nopaging' => true, // Loop through all posts at once
    'meta_key' => 'YOUR_CUSTOM_FIELD_NAME', // Replace with the name of your custom field
    'meta_value' => 'YOUR_CUSTOM_FIELD_VALUE', // The value of that field you're matching for
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {

    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();

        // Change the status of each post to pending
        $updated = wp_update_post( array('ID' => $the_query->post->ID, 'post_status' => 'pending' ));

        // Check to see if loop is returning posts, and if they were updated
        echo 'Post #' . $the_query->post->ID . ' - ' . $updated;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but no luck with that. I tried it both ways and tried with other loops on index.php removed, so only that remained, reloaded and nothing happened. Any ideas why?

Comment: Try echoing `wp_user_post` to see if it returns a post ID or just 0.

Comment: I would also include `echo $the_query->post->ID;` in the loop to make sure you're actually getting some matching posts with that query. Just updated my response with both testing methods.

Comment: Also make sure you have PHP debugging turned on so you can see any errors (in wp-config.php)

Comment: Any luck on debugging?

Comment: I didn't have a lot of luck with this initially, made all my posts pending and then back again to published. What I ended up doing was echoing out all the unapproved ids based on the meta info and then using wp_update_post on that array to change them to pending. Not the best solution probably but it worked. Final code above in original question. Accepting your answer also as it does in fact work.